# How to set and print environment variable in Power Shell?

Tags: windows-7, shell, environment-variables, powershell-2.0

I work on Windows 7 and I wont to know how to set and print environment variable in Power Shell (for example $PATH)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### List Environment Variables

```
Get-ChildItem Env:
```

### Get specific Variable

```
$Env:path
```

### Modifying/Creating Environment Variables

```
$env:TestVariable = "This is a test environment variable."
```

Additional Information: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730964.aspx?ppud=4